# Scala zio for ftp

Tags: scala, zio

I want to do sftp in zio. I have this piece of code.

```
  val settings = SecureFtpSettings("anomymous", 22, FtpCredentials("anomymous", "anomymous"))
  val sftpLayer = secure(settings)

 override def run(args: List[String]): URIO[ZEnv, ExitCode] = program.exitCode

  val program =
    for {
      files   <- connect(settings).use(_.readFile(filename).runCollect)
      lsStr   <- UIO(files.fold(new StringBuilder()){ (sb, ss) => s"${sb} ${ "" + ss}" }.toString)
      _       <- putStr(lsStr)
    } yield ()
```

When I try to read the contents of files (Chunk[Byte]), I get the output as bytes. Can anyone tell me a way of parsing a Chunk[Byte] to Strings in zio and save the contents of the file.

Comment: you can convert your `Chunk[Byte]` to ZStream and then use ZStream#transduce to convert it to `String` by passing the proper transducer. There are some predefined transducers available in ZStream.scala file. `utf8Decode` for example. If your file contains data in utf8.

Comment: Thanks @BogdanVakulenko, is there a method that will convert a Chunk[A] to a ZStream?

Comment: you can just pass your chunk to `ZStream.apply(...)` :       `ZStream(yourChunk)`